# How can I handle input in SDL?

Tags: c++, input, sdl

My SDL program wont work. It was supposed to change the image when I pressed Up. However, it changes the image only when I click on the x in the Window

```
#include "SDL.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    enum KeyPressSurfaces {
        KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_DEFAULT,
        KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_UP,
        KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_LEFT,
        KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_RIGHT,
        KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_DOWN,
        KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_TOTAL

    };
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_Event e;
    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("antena1", // window's title
        10, 25, // coordinates on the screen, in pixels, of the window's upper left corner
        640, 420, // window's length and height in pixels
        SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);

    SDL_Surface* key_press_surface[KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_TOTAL];
    SDL_Surface* gImage = NULL;
    SDL_Surface* gScreenSurface = NULL;
    bool quit = false;
    key_press_surface[KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_UP] = SDL_LoadBMP("hello_world.bmp");
    gScreenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
    gImage = SDL_LoadBMP("nick.bmp");
    if (gImage == NULL) {
        printf("Erro", SDL_GetError);
    }
    SDL_BlitSurface(gImage, NULL, gScreenSurface, NULL);
    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
    gScreenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
    while (!quit) {

        while (SDL_PollEvent(&e) == 0) {
            if (e.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                quit = true;
                //SDL_DestroyWindow(window);#
            }
            else if (e.type == SDL_KEYDOWN) {
                switch (e.key.keysym.sym) {
                case SDLK_LEFT:
                    gImage = key_press_surface[KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_UP];
                    break;
                default:
                    gScreenSurface = NULL;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    };
    SDL_BlitSurface(gImage, NULL, gScreenSurface, NULL);
    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);

    SDL_Delay(30000);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm fairly sure you need to call `SDL_BlitSurface` and `SDL_UpdateWindowSurface` inside the `while (!quit)` loop.

Comment: your mainloop does not update the image...

Comment: There are very good tutorials for SDL/SDL2 at [lazyfoo Beginning Game Programming for SDL](http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/) and [lazyfoo Beginning Game Programming for SDL2](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/index.php).

Answer (score 0):

https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PollEvent

SDL_PollEvent returns 0 if there are no events available. So per the example in the above article, in order to get into the while statement for SDL_PollEvent, there must be events in the queue. However, your code only goes into the loop if there are NO events in the queue. So anything that happens once you get there is undefined.

IOW, just remove the "== 0".